# Common limiting behavior of all cumulative distribution functions

Tags: limits, probability-distributions

Is it true that for any cumulative distribution function $F$ and any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, that $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}x^kF(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^k(1-F(x))=0$?  Clearly it's true for $k=0$, but beyond that, I have not had any success proving this claim using l'Hopital's Rule and induction.

Comment: When your abstract arguments are going nowhere, it's best to look for explicit counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

[Power law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law#Power-law_probability_distributions) distributions would serve as a counterexample.

Given some $k$, consider a distribution supported on $[0, \infty)$ with density $f(x) = \frac{1}{k} x^{-(k+1)}$. Then $1-F(x) = x^{-k}$ for $x > 0$.

"Popular" distributions (normal distribution, exponential distribution, etc.) tend to not have heavy tails and satisfy the equality in your post.